# MongoDB $and $or search query

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql

I am taking a course on MongoDB and one of the questions on the course is we need to search the data in the shell to find:

How many companies in the sample_training.companies dataset were

either founded in 2004

[and] either have the social category_code [or] web category_code,
[or] were founded in the month of October

[and] also either have the social category_code [or] web category_code?

Copy/paste the exact numeric value (without double quotes) of the result that you get into the response field.

I can't seem to get my head around this and wondered would anyone be able to help with the syntax of how I would perform this search?

Comment: You can add example  document and expected result , but will this help in your learning if somebody solve your home work instead of you ? :)

Comment: Not looking for someone to solve my homework, just asking a genuine question I'm stuck on.

Comment: The code i have tried is below but it returns zero which is not correct.

db.companies.find({
  $or: [{
    $and: [{
      founded_year: 2004
    }, {
      $or: [{
        category_code: "social"
      }, {
        category_code: "web"
      }]
    }]
  }, {
    $and: [{
      founded_month: 10
    }, {
      $or: [{
        category_code: "social"
      }, {
        category_code: "web"
      }]
    }]
  }]
}).count()

Answer (score -1):

Your own code worked for me!

```
db.companies.find({ $or: [{ $and: [{ founded_year: 2004 }, { $or: [{ category_code: "social" }, { category_code: "web" }] }] }, { $and: [{ founded_month: 10 }, { $or: [{ category_code: "social" }, { category_code: "web" }] }] }] }).count()
```

If as your other comment said, you had been getting a return of zero, it's possible you accidentally changed your dataset.

It returned to me 149 which was deemed correct.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32873937)